# Difference between \insertshorttitle and \insertsection

Tags: beamer, fontsize, warnings

I'm using a package, which provides a `beamer`-template.

The package uses `\insertshorttitle` to print the short title in the header.

To replace the short title by the section name, I replaced `\insertshorttitle` by `\insertsection`.

This works fine so far, but: If the section name contains letters like `qpgy` (letters which have a part under the "baseline") the warning `overfull vbox` is produced. This doesn't happen if the short title contains these letters. But by taking a close look, I can tell that the warning should have been also raised. So **I guess** the `\insertshorttitle` somehow suppresses the warning.

How can this also be achieved, when `\insertsection` is used?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \fontsize{6pt}{1pt}
  \selectfont
%  \insertshorttitle 
  \insertsection 
  \parbox[b]{10mm}{
    {\rule{1pt}{12mm} }
  }
}

\title[qpgy]{qpgy}

\begin{document}

\section{qpgy}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Answering this questions would require a crystal ball! You don't have to publish the package in order to create a MWE, just strip the package down to the relevant part that produces the problem - which will probably only be a couple of lines and does not reveal anything about the package.

Comment: @samcarter Ok, I finally managed to create an MWE. I thought that there might be a standard definition for `\insertshorttitle` always suppressing the warnings

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use `\strut\insertsection`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \strut\fontsize{6pt}{1pt}\selectfont
  \insertsection
  \parbox[b]{10mm}{
    {\rule{1pt}{12mm} }
  }\par
}

\title[qpgy]{qpgy}

\begin{document}

\section{qpgy}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seem's that I minimized to problem too much. Before your `\strut` my code contains `\fontsize{6pt}{1pt} \selectfont`. And with this your solution doesn't work

Comment: @Ben Does `\strut\fontsize{6pt}{1pt}\selectfont` work the mysterious code of yours?

Comment: It does! Thanks. (Then there is no `\strut` needed before `\insertsection`; but I think, you know this)

Comment: Do you think I should leave this question unaccepted, so that maybe someone comes and can explain the difference between `\insertshorttitle` and `\insertsection`?

Comment: (I also updated my question and added `\fontsize{6pt}{1pt}\selectfont`. Maybe you want to update your answer too)